# How to use sudo -i in a shell script

Tags: shell-script, sudo

Is it possible to use `sudo -i` in a shell script? I think the `exit` command will run into problems...

```
#!/bin/bash

sudo -i
curl -L https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.10.0-rc2/docker-compose-`uname -s`-`uname -m` > /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
exit
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Has been tested!... Check how the curl command has been modified...

```
#!/bin/bash

sudo -u root curl -L "https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.10.0-rc2/docker-compose-$(uname -s)-$(uname -m)" -o /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
sudo -u root chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
exit
```

Comment: Then I don't need the exit, right?

Comment: You don't, if the returning exit status of your script is trivial for you. Keep in mind that without the `exit`, the exit status will be that of the last command executed.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use `sudo` in that way.  The script would give you an interactive root shell and pause until you exited the shell. Then it would run the remaining commands in the script without `root` privileges.

If your script *only* does things that requires `root` privileges, then run the whole script with `sudo`:

```
$ sudo ./myscript.sh
```

The script would look like

```
#!/bin/bash
curl -L https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.10.0-rc2/docker-compose-`uname -s`-`uname -m` > /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
```

(Note: I haven't actually looked to see what these commands actually do)

Otherwise, and this is just a personal opinion, it may be a good idea to partition out the `root` bits out of the script and put them in scripts of their own, at least if it's common tasks.

```
#!/bin/bash

# script that does things as an ordinary user
# ...

sudo "$HOME/admin_tasks/do_docker_stuff.sudo"

# rest of script
# ...
```

Or, you could just do what everybody else seems to be doing and prefix every line in the script with `sudo`. In this case it would fail though since there's a redirection on the first line that needs `root` privileges, so you "fix it" by using `sudo bash -c " ... > ... "` instead, turning the nice and readable script into a mess of confusion (again, just a personal opinion).

**After thinking a bit:** This isn't a long script, so doing multiple `sudo` calls in the script might not be such a bad idea, but we can leave the invocation of `curl` outside of `sudo`:

```
#!/bin/bash

curl -L -o ./docker-compose "https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.10.0-rc2/docker-compose-$(uname -s)-$(uname -m)"

chmod a+x ./docker-compose

sudo mv ./docker-compose /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
sudo chown root:root /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
```

Those last three command *could* be put into a `do_local-bin_install.sudo` script (for re-use by other scripts):

```
#!/bin/bash

binary="$1"

chmod a+x "$binary"
chown root:root "$binary"
mv -i "$binary" /usr/local/bin/
```

which we could call from our script:

```
#!/bin/bash
curl -L -o ./docker-compose "https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.10.0-rc2/docker-compose-$(uname -s)-$(uname -m)"

sudo ./do_local-bin_install.sudo ./docker-compose
```

<sub>Sorry, this was a bit of an stream of consciousness type of answer. I hope someone finds it comprehensible.</sub>